# Special Price not showing on product page if Its greater than price in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I have many products for example a watch and its price is 21000 USD but its rarely available that's my special price is 22000 USD so I setup 21000 USD in **price** field and 22000 in **Special price** field but its only showing **21000 usd (price field)** on product page and not showing **special price** field value.

How can I fix this magento bug?

Please note I must display product actual price is 21000 USD and my special price 22000 usd so don't tell me to switch value in both field.

Comment: Special price is specifically designed as a catalog price discount, so I would not describe it as a bug that it can’t be used by default as a price increase.

Comment: so why this name "special price"? it name should be something like "discounted price"

Comment: It could just be a language issue. Items are said to be on “special” when they are discounted/on sale. In Magento, special price is basically an item-level sale price. There are also the Catalog Price Rules that can be used to set up catalog discounts.